# Oracle SQL Unique Constraint Violated

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I need to create tables and input values.  All but two rows when inserted give me an error, Unique Constraint Violated.  The last row in DEPT_LOCATIONS table and the second to the last row in DEPENDENT table.  I'm not sure why these rows aren't being added because other rows in the same table are.

Here's my code so far:

```
/*Create Employee Table/*
create table EMPLOYEE(FNAME varchar(30), MINIT varchar(5), LNAME varchar(30), SSN varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, BDATE varchar(30), ADDRESS varchar(30), SEX varchar(5), SALARY NUMERIC(10,0), 
SUPERSSN varchar(30),DNO varchar(30));
/*Insert values into Employee Table/* 
insert into EMPLOYEE values('John','B','Smith','123456789','1965-01-09','731 Fonden, Houston, TX','M', 30000,'333445555','5');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Franklin','T','Wong','333445555','1955-12-08','638 Voss, Houston, TX','M', 40000,'888665555','5');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Alice','J','Zelaya','999887777','1968-01-19','3321 Castle, Spring, TX','F', 25000,'987654321','4');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Jennifer','S','Walace','987654321','1941-06-20','291 Berry, Bellaire, TX','F', 43000,'888665555','4');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Ramesh','K','Narayan','666884444','1962-09-15','975 Fire Oak, Humble, TX','M', 38000,'333445555','5');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Joyce','A','English','453453453','1972-07-31','5631 Rice, Houston, TX','F', 25000,'333445555','5');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('Ahmed','V','Jabbar','987987987','1969-03-29','980 Dallas, Houston, TX','M', 25000,'987654321','4');
insert into EMPLOYEE values('James','E','Bong','888665555','1937-11-10','450 Stone, Houston, TX','M', 55000,'null','1');


/*Create Department Table*/
create table DEPARTMENT(DNAME varchar(30), DNUMBER varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY, MGRSSN varchar(30), MGRSTARTDATE varchar(30));
/*Insert values into Department Table*/
insert into DEPARTMENT values('Research', '5', '333445555', '1988-05-22');
insert into DEPARTMENT values('Administration', '4', '987654321', '1995-01-01');
insert into DEPARTMENT values('Headquarters', '1', '888665555', '1981-06-19');

/*Create Department Location Table*/
create table DEPT_LOCATIONS(DNUMBER varchar(30) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNUMBER), DLOCATION varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY);
/*Insert values into Department Location Table*/
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('1', 'Houston');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('4', 'Stafford');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Bellarire');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Sugarland');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Houston');


/*Create Project Table*/
create table PROJECT(PNAME varchar(30), PNUMBER varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY, PLOCATION varchar(30), DNUM varchar(30) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNUMBER));
/*Insert values into Project Table*/
insert into PROJECT values('ProductX', '1', 'Bellaire', '5');
insert into PROJECT values('ProductY', '2', 'Sugarland', '5');
insert into PROJECT values('ProductZ', '3', 'Houston', '5');
insert into PROJECT values('Computerization', '10', 'Stafford', '4');
insert into PROJECT values('Reorganization', '20', 'Houston', '1');
insert into PROJECT values('Newbenefits', '30', 'Stafford', '4');


/*Create Works On table*/
create table WORKS_ON(ESSN varchar(30) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN), PNO varchar(30) REFERENCES PROJECT(PNUMBER), HOURS numeric(5, 1));
/*Insert values into Works on Table*/
insert into WORKS_ON values('123456789', '1', 32.5);
insert into WORKS_ON values('123456789', '2', 7.5);
insert into WORKS_ON values('666884444', '3', 40.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('453453453', '1', 20.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('453453453', '2', 20.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('333445555', '2', 10.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('333445555', '3', 10.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('333445555', '10', 10.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('333445555', '20', 10.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('999887777', '30', 30.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('999887777', '10', 10.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('987987987', '10', 35.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('987987987', '30', 5.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('987654321', '30', 20.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('987654321', '20', 15.0);
insert into WORKS_ON values('888665555', '20', null);


/*Create Dependent table*/
create table DEPENDENT(ESSN varchar(30) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN), DEPENDENT_NAME varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY, SEX varchar(30), BDATE varchar(30), RELATIONSHIP varchar(30));
/*Insert values into Dependent Table*/
insert into DEPENDENT values('333445555', 'Alice', 'F', '1986-04-05', 'Daughter');
insert into DEPENDENT values('333445555', 'Theodore', 'M', '1983-10-25', 'Son');
insert into DEPENDENT values('333445555', 'Joy', 'F', '1958-05-03', 'Spouse');
insert into DEPENDENT values('987654321', 'Abner', 'M', '1942-02-28', 'Spouse');
insert into DEPENDENT values('123456789', 'Michael', 'M', '1988-01-04', 'Son');
insert into DEPENDENT values('123456789', 'Alice', 'F', '1988-12-30', 'Daughter');
insert into DEPENDENT values('123456789', 'Elizabeth', 'F', '1967-05-05', 'Spouse');
```

The tables should look like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5O3s.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ksg.jpg)

Could someone please help me understand what is going on? 
Thank you

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy OP has actually provided all the table DDL and DML in text in the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LalitKumarB There's no specification. Stuff in the links should be text in the question. There's no attempt to debug. A [mre] isn't just the code.

Comment: @philipxy Agree with you. For a trivial question, I found the details enough to provide an answer. As a new poster I think OP did a good job, and I hope in future OP would try to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DLOCATION varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY
>
> insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('1', 'Houston');
>
> insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Houston');

The `DLOCATION` column is a **primary key**, but you are trying to insert **duplicate values** `'Houston'` into the table. Therefore it throws `unique constraint violated` error. To overcome this, you could create it as a **composite primary key** with `DNUMBER` and `DLOCATION` together as:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_num_loc PRIMARY KEY (DNUMBER, DLOCATION)
```

**DDL & inserts:**

```
/*Create Department Location Table*/
CREATE TABLE dept_locations (
dnumber     VARCHAR(30)
  REFERENCES department ( dnumber ),
dlocation   VARCHAR(30),
  CONSTRAINT pk_num_loc PRIMARY KEY ( dnumber, dlocation ));

insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('1', 'Houston');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('4', 'Stafford');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Bellarire');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Sugarland');
insert into DEPT_LOCATIONS values('5', 'Houston');

SELECT * FROM dept_locations;
```

**Output:**

```
DNUMBER DLOCATION                     
------- ------------------------------
1       Houston                       
4       Stafford                      
5       Bellarire                     
5       Houston                       
5       Sugarland
```

Similarly, you need to do the same for rest of the tables which are failing due to unique constraint error.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you violated the primary key of the table, which must be unique. "Houston" is repeated for DEPT_LOCATIONS, as is "Alice" for DEPENDENTS.

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix this? How do I allow the primary key to have duplicate values?

Comment: @TianaChargin  Part of the definition of "primary key" is that it can't have duplicate values.  If these fields need to have duplicates, they should not be primary keys at all.

Comment: A combination of columns could be unique and therefore could be a candidate for a composite primary key.

Comment: Another common approach is to have a primary key column / unique identifier that is just a counter of some kind, so that every row gets a unique "id" number.

Comment: @pmdba Basically an identity column.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yes.